# DIfferent versions of ruby in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I recently started following M Hartls tutorials on how to build a simple app using RoR.
I nearly wasted one full day on installing RVM and the ruby, since the default RVM on ubuntu is buggy. Once I install ruby through RVM

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

it says it installed ruby 2.x version.

but when I type

> ruby -v

It says the ruby version is 1.8.x. Why is that?

Comment: Try `rvm use ruby-2.0`. Did you restart your console to ensure that the new environment was also in use?

Comment: In my gemfile, it says ruby 2.0.0 and when I try to `bundle update`, it says `evaluate': undefined method 'ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0xb7301a80> (NoMethodError)
`

Comment: `which ruby` - if it's `/usr/bin/ruby` or similar, you'll probably find that the system ruby's path is higher up in your $PATH

Answer (score 1):

Your default ruby version is set to 1.8.x.

Type "rvm list" to list installed ruby versions "*" will appear next to your default.

Type "rvm use x.x.x" to use a different version of ruby.

To set a different default version of ruby type "rvm --default use x.x.x".

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the message given after installing RVM. It's something like:

> Please make sure the following line is somewhere in your .bashrc:

```
source /home/<username>/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

What is the output of `ruby -v` after you executed that line in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM then:
do

```
rvm list
```

this will show list of installed rubies

and the do

```
rvm use XXXXXXX
```

XXXXX means the version you want to use from the list.

This will use the specified ruby. but after opening new terminal it might be again changed automatically. To avoid this use :

```
rvm use XXXXXX --default
```

**For example of mine system:**

```
rvm list
```

rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]

=* ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]

```
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rvm use 2.0.0
```

Using .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451

```
$ rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

Using .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451